# Existence of the holomorphic solution of this equation

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm interested in knowing if the following equation 
$$(f(z))^{2016}=z+1$$
has a solution $f$, which is holomorphic on $|z|<2$.

Firstly, it seems that I would need to search for something like $\exp(\frac{1}{2016}\log(z+1))$. But it seems that $\log(z+1)$ can't be continuously defined on $\{z:|z|<2\}\backslash\{-1\}$, because, integral of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{z+1}$ on a loop around -1 is $2\pi i$. If $\log(z+1)$ could've been defined there, it would be an antiderivative of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{z+1}$, so the integral should have been 0 instead.

But would the non-existence of $\log(z+1)$ imply non-existence of holomorphic $f$ on $|z|<2$? Or, maybe I should have tried some other approach...

Comment: Hmm. But I just noticed that maybe I don't need to worry about continuity of $\log(z+1)$ to use $\exp(\frac{1}{2016}\log(z+1))$, maybe this would still be continuous and even holomorphic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try expanding $f$ as a Taylor series around $-1$: $$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k (z+1)^k.$$ Certainly $a_0 = f(-1) = 0,$ but then you run into a problem when you try to set $f(z)^{2016} = z+1.$

Basically the problem is that a holomorphic function can't vanish in $-1$ with order $1/2016.$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that such a function $f$ exists. Then $f(-1) = 0$. (Since $w=0$ is the only solution to $w^{2016} = 0$.) Differentiating the equation gives us
$$
2016\, f'(z) (f(z))^{2015} = 1
$$
but plugging in $z=-1$ leads to a contradiction. Hence, no such function can exist.